# Append javascript and jQuery file to a webpage from asset

Tags: javascript, html

I am displaying a webpage from a server in webview. However to handle some functionality I want to add 3-4 files from asset folder to the webpage.

How do you append these files to the webpage that also has some of its own javascript?

> ```
> <head>
>     <script src='jquery.js'></script>
> </head>
> ```

Comment: look in the console and see what file cannot be find - and what its looking for. Change the `src` path until it matches the actual location.

Answer (score 0):

Paths that dont start with / are relative so try :

```
<script src='assets/jquery.js'></script>
```

this will work if your html files are in a directory / folder that contains an assets folder with the JavaScript library within that

if you want to specify an absolute path use

```
<script src='/assets/jquery.js'></script>
```

this will work if the assets folder is a sub folder of the document root directory

Comment: similarly can you tell me the way to add javascript from server folder

Comment: @Daniel change assets to server ? i think im missing the point of your question - are you using some kind of framework ?

Comment: i added as you told but those javascript not working ,here you can see the html file-

Comment: Actually if the html file is with js files so its working but if some js file is on server and some are in asset so that time it is not working

Comment: check below in answer i added the file .

Answer (score 0):

i added as you told but those javascript not working ,here you can see the html file-                                         `

1. > ```
   > <!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head> <script   
   >     src='/assets/jquery.js'></script><script   
   >     src='/assets/rangy-core.js'></script><script   
   >     src='/assets/rangy-serializer.js'></script><script   
   >     src='/assets/android.selection.js'></script><title>Kendal Hunt -   
   >     Psychology - Brown CH, Foster JD, Gordon MS</title><meta   
   >     http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><link
   >     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"
   >     title="style"    /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
   >     href="style/brl.css"    /><script
   >     src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script></head>
   > ```

`